# Pandas check for corresponding column in list and lowest date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple status fields per row. I want to check if any of the status fields have values in a list, and if so, I need to take the lowest date field for the corresponding status. My list of acceptable values and a sample dataframe look like this:

```
checkList = ['Foo','Bar']

df = pd.DataFrame([['A',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],['B','Foo',datetime.datetime(2017,10,1),'Other',datetime.datetime(2017,9,1),np.nan,np.nan],
                  ['C','Bar',datetime.datetime(2016,1,1),np.nan,np.nan,'Foo',datetime.datetime(2016,5,5)]]
                ,columns = ['record','status1','status1_date','status2','status2_date','another_status','another_status_date'])

print df

 record status1 status1_date status2 status2_date another_status  \
0      A     NaN          NaT     NaN          NaT            NaN   
1      B     Foo   2017-10-01   Other   2017-09-01            NaN   
2      C     Bar   2016-01-01     NaN          NaT            Foo   

  another_status_date  
0                 NaT  
1                 NaT  
2          2016-05-05
```

I need to figure out if any of the statuses are in the approved list. If so, I need the first date for an approved status.  The output would look like this:

```
print output_df

  record master_status master_status_date
0      A         False                NaT
1      B          True         2017-10-01
2      C          True         2016-01-01
```

Thoughts on how best to approach? I can't just take min date, I'd need min where corresponding status field is in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
master_status = df.apply(lambda x: False if all([pd.isnull(rec) for rec in x[1:]]) else True, axis=1)
master_status_date = df.apply(lambda x: min([i for i in x[1:] if isinstance(i, datetime.datetime)]), axis=1)
record = df['record']


n_df = pd.concat([record, master_status, master_status_date], 1)

print(n_df)
  record      0          1
0      A   False        NaT
1      B   True   2017-09-01
2      C   True   2016-01-01
```

Comment: Thanks - that's close but I have other datetime columns in my actual dataset, can't rely on datatype